# Kong Custom Plugin Admin Interface extension : need access to config of plugin

Tags: kong, kong-plugin

I'm building a custom plugin and I'm extending the admin interface via **api.lua**

Functions have the 'self' property where i can get request information but I also need access to the plugin configuration (like **handler.lua**) .

How can I do that ?

Kong 2.7.0.

```
return {
    ["/my-route/:id"] = {
        GET = function(self)
        -- do some stuff
        end
    }    
}
```

Thx,

Peter

**Update**

schema.lua

```
return {
    no_consumer = true, -- this plugin will only be API-wide
    fields = {
        redis_host = { type = "string" },
        redis_port = { type = "number", default = 6379 },
        redis_password = { type = "string" },
        redis_timeout = { type = "number", default = 2000 },
        redis_database = { type = "number", default = 1 }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should have what you declare on`schema.lua` available.

Comment: @Ôrel , I added schema.lua. How do I get the runtime value of the plugin configuration of e.g. redis_host in api.lua ?

Comment: There is nothing to do, just use plugins API  cf https://docs.konghq.com/gateway/2.7.x/admin-api/#plugin-object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate on each plugins to get all your instance by name

```lua
local function each_my_plugin()
  local iter = kong.db.plugins:each()

  return function()
    while true do
      local plugin, err = iter()
      if err then
        return kong.response.exit(500, { message = err })
      end
      if not plugin then
        return
      end
      if plugin.name == "my plugin" then
        return plugin
      end
    end
  end
end
```

or by id

```lua
kong.db.plugins:select {id = id }
```